# Make Div take up the remaining width

Tags: html, css

Basically I have 2 DIVs. One has a fixed width. Now I want the other one take up the remaining width.

I can only acheive this by putting the float on the fixed-width-div - which for me is the one to the right. But it only works when I swap out the DIVs in my HTML (right one comes first). I don't like having it this way.

So is there any way to get this exact setup, but without having to swap out the DIVs in my HTML?

Here's a JSFiddle for clarification

https://jsfiddle.net/MHeqG/1862/

HTML (When I put the left DIV first the float breaks)

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="right">
        right
    </div>
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
    width: 300px;
}
#left {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    background-color:#00FF00;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and use `display:flex;`, I think it gets you what you want.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xvjbb75/)

Comment: Ooh, I like that. Nicer option than using `calc()` - don't have to worry about fixed widths and calculating them

Comment: check this out for flex support: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp. Very limited

Comment: @Dimitri Its not that limited, the main browsers you have to watch out for are IE9 and below and early iOS browsers. But ya there are some limitations

Comment: @Dimitri also you linked support to the wrong CSS property. The correct one is [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Comment: Wow ok. This seems like the cleanest solution to my problem. I should really consider getting into flexbox.

Comment: @Georgi [Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a good explanation of flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of CSS `calc()` function

```css
#wrap {
    width: 300px;
}
#left {
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    background-color:#00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="right">
        right
    </div>
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Go to http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc to check for browser support. I would avoid using this function if cross-browser compatibility is a goal.

Comment: @Dimitri one of the burdens of using CSS3. It's not widely unsupported though, I don't think we are all trying to cater to the 2% of people that still use old IE or Android browsers

Comment: for a website with one million visitors a month 2% is 20,000 unique users. I wouldn't dismiss that

Comment: @Georgi yeah! I was overjoyed the first time I came across that. Because you can now make calculation with % and px

Comment: @Dimitri valid point - I would just check the site analytics before making that assumption. However, this is supported by 83% of internet users globally

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

https://jsfiddle.net/MHeqG/1864/

CSS:

```
#wrap {
    position:relative;
    width: 300px;
}
#left {
    margin-right:55px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
#right {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width: 50px;
    background-color:#00FF00;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That sounds like an idea. Will keep it in mind if this appears to be the only solution.

Comment: @Georgi - Since you're specifying fixed width of the wrapper can you use fixed width for the left div as well? If so, you could just float both divs to left and clearfix the wrapper.

Comment: Ah sorry should've added this info. The wrapper actually has max-width of 1200px in my code. So It's meant to shrink with the browser-window.